# Using loop with sql in Dbvisualizeer (database Vertica)

Tags: sql, vertica

I am trying to execute sql statement withing loop in Dbvisualizer

```
--/
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1, @MaxEmployeeId INT = 3 

WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @MaxEmployeeId)
BEGIN
select * from payment
where payment_date='2017-05-11' 
END;
/
```

The above code is giving me syntax error.
It is possible to run statements in a loop and if yes, how can i create a loop for  date range - ( from 11 may to 15 may).
Note: (--/ and / are written assuming block in sql)

Comment: Where in the [Vertica manual](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm) did you find that syntax?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Found it on net not in vertica mannual

Comment: You shouldn't trust stuff "you find on the net" unless you can verify it in the manual or that random finding **explicitely** tells you the solution is for Vertica (not just "SQL" in general). You probably found something that is meant for SQL Server, not for Vertica.

Comment: Is there any way i can loop dates in sql statement to run on vertica?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can i run sql statements and loop over dates in sql ( for vertica )

Answer (score 1):

No. Vertica does not support loops in its plain SQL syntax.

Also: remember that SQL is a descriptive, set oriented, not a procedural language, and that this is what the ANSI standard, to which Vertica adheres completely, is based upon.

As a specialised Big Data platform, Vertica optimises its mass data access paths itself; and nested loops, as they result from a procedure that you suggest, are avoided using different strategies.

You might consider writing a User Defined scalar, transform or aggregate function. Scalar in Python, R, Java or C++; Transform in R, Java or C++; Aggregate only in C++.

But to solve your problem, I would remain set oriented - and just create a set (i.e an in-line table) in my query, and CROSS JOIN the base query with that.

Vertica has the TIMESERIES clause, which you can also use to generate rows out of (almost) nothing ...

Like so:

```
WITH
-- create a series of integers, call it "index" with column name "loopcounter"
-- replace 3 in "now() +   3 - 1" with your actual number of employees
index(loopcounter) AS (
  SELECT row_number() OVER ()
  FROM (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (
                SELECT now()           AS se
      UNION ALL SELECT now() +   3 - 1 AS se 
    ) limits 
    TIMESERIES ts AS '1 day' OVER (ORDER BY se)
  ) tstab
)
SELECT
  *
FROM payment
CROSS JOIN index
WHERE payment_date = '2017-05-11'
;
```